# My PSN avatar keeps changing to default one. How can I stop it?

Tags: psn

This is a really weird issue, but my PSN avatar is changed to default one every week or two. I have no idea why. I only use my PSN account from PS4. It's very annoying to change it back to something all the time. I've searched online, but found only some "me too" threads ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/bg2x0i/playstation_4_avatar_reverted_back_to_default_on/), [2](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/71218-psn-avatar-resetting/)).

How can I stop my avatar from resetting?